# Approximation of $\sum_{\substack{n\geq 1\\n\text{ is abundant}}}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^3}$, where $\sigma(n)$ denotes the sum of divisors function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, divisors-multiples

Let $\sigma(n)=\sum_{1\leq d\mid n}d$ the sum of divisors function then, from the theory of Dirichlet series, it is well-known the value of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^3},$$
in terms of particular values of the Riemann zeta function, see for example [1].

On the other hand an integer  is an abundant number, if $\sigma(n)>2n$. For example $n=24$ is abundant, $\sigma(24)=60$. See the Wikipedia [*Abundant number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number) as a reference for this post.

We denote the set of abundant numbers as $\mathcal{A}$, it is *A005101* from the OEIS.

I wondered about the following question. I don't know if this question is in the literature or if it is feasible to do some work about it.

> **Question.** What work can be done about an approximation of $$\sum_{\substack{n\geq 1\\n\in\mathcal{A}}}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^3}?$$
>   **Many thanks.**

If it is well-known from the literature, add the reference and I try to search and read the corresponding statement from the literature.

### References:

[1] Tom. M. Apostol, *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, Springer (1976).

Comment: ...you can just compute the approximation. It's $0.052572\dots$

Comment: Do you think @Wojowu that the downvoter here know how get an approximation $\sum_{\substack{n\geq 1\\n\text{ abundant}}}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^3}$?

Comment: Yes, they do, because I am the downvoter and I gave you an approximation.

Comment: With all respect to you, you know what is that I am asking with my Question, and it is a scientific question. As I said I can't put aside my appreciation for you as user that help me with attention in this site @Wojowu

Comment: No, I honestly have no idea what you are asking for if not a numerical approximation